# Travel to Italy Via Germany Using US Refugee Travel Document

Tags: air-travel, usa, schengen, trains, visas-on-arrival

I am leaving for a trip to Italy with a layover in Germany. I know that I don't need a visa for Germany, but would I be able to transfer into Italy without a Visa? I would have gotten it earlier, but my travel document was just issued and my flight is 5 days of the date of issue. I did try to go the the Italian consulate and he refused to even look at my application considering the amount of time needed to process it. I was born in Vietnam, but being a refugee, doesn't that mean I am stateless? So lost. My flight was booked by a friend to help out with a photoshoot.

Does Italy issue visa on arrival or will I be flat-out rejected at boarding?

Comment: There is a good chance you won't be checked at boarding since there are no formal border controls between Germany and Italy.  But you would be entering Italy illegally, if I read the Italian information correctly, and if you were checked, you could be subject, presumably, to expulsion, and/or a fine and/or an entry ban.